# Which view has cache_value of sequences?

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a query which retrieves a list of sequences on pgsql-9.1.6. Please see my SQL  set below...

```
mydb=# create sequence seq1 cache 10;
CREATE SEQUENCE
mydb=# create sequence seq2 cache 20; 
CREATE SEQUENCE
mydb=# \ds
        List of relations
 Schema | Name |   Type   | Owner 
--------+------+----------+-------
 public | seq1 | sequence | pgdba
 public | seq2 | sequence | pgdba
(2 rows)

mydb=# \x
Expanded display is on.
mydb=# select * from seq1;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | seq1
last_value    | 1
start_value   | 1
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 10
log_cnt       | 0
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | f

mydb=# select * from seq2;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | seq2
last_value    | 1
start_value   | 1
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 20
log_cnt       | 0
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | f

mydb=# select * from information_schema.sequences;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------+--------------------
sequence_catalog        | mydb
sequence_schema         | public
sequence_name           | seq1
data_type               | bigint
numeric_precision       | 64
numeric_precision_radix | 2
numeric_scale           | 0
start_value             | 1
minimum_value           | 1
maximum_value           | 9223372036854775807
increment               | 1
cycle_option            | NO
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------+--------------------
sequence_catalog        | mydb
sequence_schema         | public
sequence_name           | seq2
data_type               | bigint
numeric_precision       | 64
numeric_precision_radix | 2
numeric_scale           | 0
start_value             | 1
minimum_value           | 1
maximum_value           | 9223372036854775807
increment               | 1
cycle_option            | NO
```

**information_schema.sequences** has no cache_value. Which view can I join to get `cache_value` with my sequence list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I'm aware, you're actually viewing where this data is stored right there... The table name is that of the sequence itself. There is no view in the formation schema because it's an implementation detail relatd to Postgres.

Side note: Postgres uses the pg_catalog to create views for within the information schema. The latter really is a cross-platform convenience; the real details are in the catalog. Don't miss psql's `--echo-hidden` option to find out more about the internals:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

---

```
# Output using `psql -E`

test=# create sequence test;
CREATE SEQUENCE
test=# \d+ test
********* QUERY **********
SELECT c.oid,
  n.nspname,
  c.relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname ~ '^(test)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 2, 3;
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT c.relchecks, c.relkind, c.relhasindex, c.relhasrules, c.relhastriggers, c.relhasoids, pg_catalog.array_to_string(c.reloptions || array(select 'toast.' || x from pg_catalog.unnest(tc.reloptions) x), ', ')
, c.reltablespace, CASE WHEN c.reloftype = 0 THEN '' ELSE c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype::pg_catalog.text END, c.relpersistence
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class tc ON (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid)
WHERE c.oid = '25356';
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT * FROM public.test;
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
  a.attnotnull, a.attnum,
  (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation c, pg_catalog.pg_type t
   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation) AS attcollation,
  NULL AS indexdef,
  NULL AS attfdwoptions,
  a.attstorage,
  CASE WHEN a.attstattarget=-1 THEN NULL ELSE a.attstattarget END AS attstattarget
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = '25356' AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.' ||
   pg_catalog.quote_ident(relname) || '.' ||
   pg_catalog.quote_ident(attname)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend d ON c.oid=d.refobjid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute a ON (
 a.attrelid=c.oid AND
 a.attnum=d.refobjsubid)
WHERE d.classid='pg_catalog.pg_class'::pg_catalog.regclass
 AND d.refclassid='pg_catalog.pg_class'::pg_catalog.regclass
 AND d.objid=25356
 AND d.deptype='a'
**************************

                 Sequence "public.test"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        | Storage 
---------------+---------+---------------------+---------
 sequence_name | name    | test                | plain
 last_value    | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 start_value   | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807 | plain
 min_value     | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0                   | plain
 is_cycled     | boolean | f                   | plain
 is_called     | boolean | f                   | plain

test=#
```

Comment: Is there any altanative way to get that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but someone with more familiarity with the internals might chime and beg to differ. As I understand them, though, Postgres sequences amount to a single-row table, with the relevant data related to the sequence (apart from its name) within that row. If you enable the `-E` option (to echo hidden queries), per my updated answer, you'll note that the information is fetched from pg_class, pg_attributes, etc. as well as the "sequence/table" itself: `SELECT * FROM public.test`.